# Getting a link to a Wolfram Cloud notebook from a WolframScript query?

Tags: scripting

Is there a way to make something like

```
wolframscript -code 'Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]' -cloud
```

spin up a new Wolfram Online notebook with the output from above? This would be especially useful to inspect the output of interactive graphs.

Answer (score 1):

This works on my desktop Mathematica installation, wolframscript command line (as argument to `wolframscript -code`):

```
CloudDeploy@
 Notebook[{Cell@BoxData@ToBoxes@Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]}]
```

> CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"]

The link provided by `CloudObject` can be opened in a browser and features a rotatable 3D plot.

You probably also want to destroy (or refresh) these deployed objects. I'm not commenting on that.